# Delphi: Upgrade From D5 to D7 Hang at Compile

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I wrote my code in D5, then I switched to D7. Things are ok, until compile. D7 appears hang and I have to killed the process. I already deleted all the DCUs and the problem persists.

Anybody had this problem before?

Thanks!

Comment: What operating systems are you using? Did you install the update pack? Can you spot where actually the compiler hangs?

Comment: I use XP Pro, D7 Update 1 and D5 Update 2. When I press F9 it's just hang. All Delphi screen goes white, and RAM use in the range of 140K

Comment: "Things are OK until compile." So, in other words, things are not OK at all.

Comment: Can you compile a new, blank project? Maybe this has nothing to do with your Delphi 5 project.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to make the compilation via the command line compiler?

I suggest you install Delphi Speed Up from http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/delphispeedup

You could also download the CnPack from http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en
There are some options to Set the IDE to run in CPU 0 single core.

Try to create a new project, then add your units one by one, until it freezes...

Comment: I found out that the cause of it: ZeosLib (I use v. 6.6.6). When I remove all zeos references, i can compile normally. I actually like zeoslib, but what happened makes me reluctant to use it again.

Answer (score 0):

What .Net FrameWork is installed in your system?

Try this
**Project|Options|Compiler Messages dialog**, there's a long list of checkboxes. The last three have to do with the Dot Net Versions.Have you unchecked those last three? I think it would not work for you, or reinstall Delphi once.

I not faced such situation (D7 in Win7 )

Comment: The last three are unchecked. I try to avoid reinstalling D7 (i already search the internet and there's a mention that reinstalling doesn't solve it)

Comment: can u explore your problem? D5 compiled project open in D7 hangs it or any file in D7 hangs. 

just open dpr files and re compile...

Comment: Delphi 7 doesn't use the .NET framework at all. Those compiler mesages are there just to spot probable issue in source code and print a warning, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Try: "Project/Build All Project"
And be sure that is checket switch: "Tools/Enviroment Options/Preferences/Show compiler progress".
Than tell as where compiler stops.